# Google script onEdit(e) not working with idividual workbooks on mobile

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet with some script running behind it, that sends the data from one workbook to another. Where one acts as an input form, while the other collects the information from that form. Everything was working fine as long as both the input form and the database were sitting on the same google sheet. When separating one from the other I discovered that the code is no longer working properly.

Unfortunately, I cannot create buttons to trigger specific action, because the form is intended to be used solely on mobile.

Perhaps someone could be so kind and help me modify the code to work again, please?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iq1m7.png)

```
enter code here
function ClearCell() {
var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var forms   = ss.getSheetByName("Formularz");

var rangesToClear = ["F4" , "D5" , "D6" , "D7" , "D8" , "D9" , "D10" , "D11"];
for (var i=0; i<rangesToClear.length; i++) {
forms.getRange(rangesToClear[i]).clearContent();
}
}
```

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
function SubmitData() {
var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var forms     = ss.getSheetByName("Formularz");
var ss_new    = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxx');
var datas     = ss_new.getSheetByName("Lokale");

var values = [[forms.getRange("F4").getValue(),
             forms.getRange("B2").getValue(),
             forms.getRange("B4").getValue(),
            forms.getRange("D2").getValue(),
            forms.getRange("C4").getValue(),
             forms.getRange("D5").getValue(),
forms.getRange("D6").getValue(),
forms.getRange("D7").getValue(),
forms.getRange("D8").getValue(),
forms.getRange("D9").getValue(),
forms.getRange("D10").getValue(),
forms.getRange("D11").getValue()]];
datas.getRange(datas.getLastRow()+1,1,1,12).setValues(values);
ClearCell();
}
```

//-------------------------------------------------------------------

```
var SEARCH_COL_INDX = 0;
function Search() {

var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var forms    = ss.getSheetByName("Formularz");
var ss_new    = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxx');

var str  = forms.getRange("E4").getValue();
var values = ss_new.getSheetByName("Lokale").getDataRange().getValues();
for (var i = 0; i< values.length; i++) {
var row = values[i];
if (row[SEARCH_COL_INDX] == str) {

  forms.getRange("F4").setValue(row[0]);
    forms.getRange("B2").setValue(row[1]);
    forms.getRange("B4").setValue(row[2]);
    forms.getRange("D2").setValue(row[3]);
    forms.getRange("C4").setValue(row[4]);
    forms.getRange("D5").setValue(row[5]);
    forms.getRange("D6").setValue(row[6]);
    forms.getRange("D7").setValue(row[7]);
    forms.getRange("D8").setValue(row[8]);
    forms.getRange("D9").setValue(row[9]);
    forms.getRange("D10").setValue(row[10]);
    forms.getRange("D11").setValue(row[11]);
    
    }
   }
   }
```

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
  function Update() {
  var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var forms     = ss.getSheetByName("Formularz");
  var ss_new    = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxxx');
  var datas     = ss_new.getSheetByName("Lokale");

  var str  = forms.getRange("E4").getValue();
  var values = ss_new.getSheetByName("Data").getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i< values.length; i++) {
  var row = values[i];
  if (row[SEARCH_COL_INDX] == str) {
  var INT_R = i+1

   var values1 = [[forms.getRange("F4").getValue(),
             forms.getRange("B2").getValue(),
             forms.getRange("B4").getValue(),
            forms.getRange("D2").getValue(),
            forms.getRange("C4").getValue(),
             forms.getRange("D5").getValue(),
  forms.getRange("D6").getValue(),
  forms.getRange("D7").getValue(),
  forms.getRange("D8").getValue(),
  forms.getRange("D9").getValue(),
  forms.getRange("D10").getValue(),
  forms.getRange("D11").getValue()]];

  datas.getRange(INT_R,1,1,12).setValues(values1);
  ClearCell();
 }
 }
}


function onEdit(e) {
if (e.range.getA1Notation() == 'D4') {
if (/^\w+$/.test(e.value)) {        
  eval(e.value)();
  e.range.clear();
}
}
}
```

Comment: @Ron M would you be able to help Sir?

Comment: Can you share your sample sheet as reference? just to have some idea (with sample data) you can redact private information in your sheet. Also please remove your previous comment. Others might be able to help as well beside me but I'll try to replicate this on my end as well

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/138382/how-to-share-a-google-sheets-demo-spreadsheet/138383#138383

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your `onEdit()` trigger is not working is because you need an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) instead of a [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) since you are trying to access a different spreadsheet which requires authorization.

> Installable triggers, offer more flexibility than simple triggers which can call services that require authorization.

Before, when both your source and destination sheet is within a common spreadsheet, authorization is not required. I was able to verify this when I checked the execution log based on your original code. You can check that in `Apps Script Executions Tab`.

[image]

---

### [Managing triggers manually](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually)

[image]

[image]

---

### Note:

- Don't forget to include `SubmitData` in your data validation list to trigger `SubmitData()`
- I just noticed some unclear procedure in your `Update()`. You submit new data to `lokale` sheet, but when you call `Update()` you are trying to read data from `Data` sheet. But if this is an expected behavior you can ignore this.
- Don't forget that when using `Search()` and `Update()` you are reading cell `E4` which is grayed out in your sample image, while using `F4` as your original tag which is also grayed out.
- I advised you to include further condition in your `onEdit()` to make sure that your function will only be triggered for `Formularz!D4` modification. Include checking of current active sheet name

**sample code:**

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = e.source;
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  if (e.range.getA1Notation() == 'D4' && sheet.getName() == "Formularz") {
    if (/^\w+$/.test(e.value)) {        
      eval(e.value)();
      e.range.clear();
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for your great remarks! Since I've changed the simple trigger to installable as you suggested everything works properly :) Thank you again for your time and attention dedicated to solving my issue, you are the best! Wish you a great week ahead , kind greetings from Poland! D.

Comment: @ Ron M , hope you were able to see my comment  @Ron M ;)

Comment: yes Sir, indeed you've had helped me a ton and I'm very much grateful to you :) All the Best !